# How to count duplicate records in all the tables in Snowflake Database?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I would like to create a Data Quality table in the `Snowflake` database, where I can maintain a record of all duplicate records present in all the tables within multiple schemas. I have 5-6 schemas, each containing more than 10 tables. I would like to create a VIEW or BASE table that allows me to track and monitor duplicates. However, since I am new to `Snowflake` and stored procedures, I'm unsure about the best approach to achieve this.

Any help on this topic will be really helpful!!

Thanks in advance for your time and efforts!

***[Update based on Himanshu Kandpal request]***

[image]

Column C contains Unique Key

Comment: Hi One way you could do is to create a View which will contain the following columns, like  Schema_Name, Table_mame, Unique_cols (this will contain the list of columns making up the unique columns, Unique_colS_Val (this will be concatenated list of values making up the unique key ). You will use a SELECT count(*), list of cols  From table_name group by list of cols having count(*) > 1 to populate your View. If your tables are very big then you will use a Procedure to populate the table using the same query that you used to create the View.

Comment: @Himanshu Kandpal- Would it be possible for you to provide code ?

Comment: Can you please send a sample table structure and columns making up the unique keys.

Comment: you should make columns unique so that duplicates can't happen at all. also  a trigger that check for duplicates and inserts into your new table, would be faster as running a view

Comment: @ Himanshu Kandpal- Please see update question. Column C contains Unique key.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do is Create a View which will contain the following columns, like
Schema_Name , Table_mame, Unique_cols (this will contain the list of columns making up the unique columns, Unique_colS_Val (this will be concatenated list of values making up the unique key ).

-- Untested

```
Create or replace view Duplicate_data_CHK AS

SELECT 'SCHEMA_NM' AS Schema_Name,
'TAB_NM' as Table_name,
'C' AS Unique_cols ,
C , COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY C
having count(*) > 1;
```